# jQuery selector using regex (or something else)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to select an attribute in my code that match a string+number in the class name, using jQuery

What I need to do is to match something like that:

```
var myVar = 'item';
$('#id [class="'+myVar+'\d+"]');
```

My code contain other classes starting by "item" as well, so I can't use the selector  `class^="item"`

I found out different things on Internet, but nothing that match perfectly my requirement.

I found the jQuery extension ":regex" but I'm not allowed to use it. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

I found the use of "filter" as a function but this is horrible for the performance
[jQuery filter selector, is this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964810/jquery-filter-selector-is-this-right)

I tried to do something but it's not even working:

```
$('#id *').filter(function() {
   return this.className.match("/"+myVar+"\d/");
});
```

Do you have some better suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you need to use Regex _IS_ horrible for performance and indicates for a bad design.filter is fine (as fine as it can be) but your selector `*` is the reason for the slowness

Comment: Can't you change your class names? For example instead of item1234, call it item_1234 with `_` meaning that a number follows.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to rename the classes for these items to something that is not the prefix of another class on your page (or add an additional class to them). Then you can use the selector `[class^='yourNewClassPrefix']` (or just a normal class selector if you added an additional class). This would be much faster and better design than anything requiring regular expressions.

Comment: @Christophe beat me to my answer by 10 seconds :)

Comment: I'm not able to rename classes unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use `\d` with CSS/jQuery selectors.

I suggest you split the number out into another attribute like `data-number` or something. This way you can target the class easily and efficiently and still have the number available.

```
<span class="my-class" data-number="1"></span>
<span class="my-class" data-number="6"></span>
<span class="my-class" data-number="10"></span>
```

**jQuery example**

```
$.each($('my-class'), function () {
    $(this).attr('data-number');
});
```

As @Asad mentions they can also be selected using `$('.my-class[data-number="1"]')`.

Comment: These can then be selected using `.my-class[data-number="n"]`, where n is your desired number.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('#id [class*=' + myVar + ']').filter(function() {
   return this.className.match(new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + myVar + '\\d+(\\s|$)'));
});
```

**[Check jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/HZdnE/1)**.

The selector picks every descendant element of `#id` with `myVar` in a class name. Finally it filters them, leaving only those who have `myVar` followed by one or more of digits as the name of one of its classes.

<sub>**Note:** You probably aready know that, but it is worth warning anyway: you must prevent `myVar` from having chars with special meaning to selectors (which would mess the `[class*=' + myVar + ']'` selector) and [to regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) (such as the string `'[a-z]'`, which would make the regex match a range instead of the literal `'[a-z]'` -- in this case, it should be escaped, as `'\[a-z\]'`).</sub>